# How to enter Windows-Subsystem-for-Linux (ubuntu) from PowerShell at the current PowerShell working dir

Tags: bash, powershell, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When running the command `bash` or `ubuntu` in PowerShell, the Windows-Subsystem-for-Linux is entered, however, the current working dir for PowerShell is not carried across to BASH. Is there a way to implement this functionality?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From your Windows Powershell or Powershell Core window, type `bash` (or wsl); for example:

[image]

Now, later versions of Windows include WSL.exe, which replaces bash.exe. The behavior of both executable is the same on my system. The official documentation for wsl.exe states:

[image]

You can read that documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/interop). Net-net,

I'm running Windows 10 Build-17763. If you aren't experiencing the same behavior I am, you might be running an older version of WSL. You can determine the version of WSL from your build number.

Comment: At least in my case, the bash shell is entered, except not at the current working dir.